# why is JavaScript Closure returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I know something very basic I am missing . But can't find what's wrong with it ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A function can access variables defined inside the function:</p>

<button type="button" onclick="alert(makeMyCounter.increment)">Click Me!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var makeMyCounter = function () {
        var privateCounter = 0; 


        return {
            increment : function() {
                privateCounter += 1;
            },
            decrement : function() {
                privateCounter += -1;
            }
        }
    }();


</script>

</body>
```

Why is privateCounter returning undefined ? But when debugged via browser , it is being assigned 1 though .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using method reference as property, to call method properly use it like that:

```
makeMyCounter.increment()
```

next thing You not return in method so it will be undefined. Add return:

```
return {
        increment : function() {
            return privateCounter += 1;

        },
        decrement : function() {
            return privateCounter += -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`privateCounter` isn't a function, so it doesn't return anything.

`increment` is a function, but you didn't put `()` after it, so you aren't calling it and it will alert the result of converting the function to a string.

If you were to call it (`alert(makeMyCounter.increment());`), then it would return `undefined` because it has no `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your function you just increment its value but there is no return statement.

In javascript if your function has no return statement `undefined` will be returned by default.

if you need your new value return `privateCounter` in `increment` and `decrement` functions

```
    return {
        increment : function() {
            privateCounter += 1;
            return privateCounter;
        },
        decrement : function() {
            privateCounter += -1;
            return privateCounter;
        }
    }
```